# Permission probems trying to save txt file to var/html

Tags: filesystem

I am learning PHP on my local machine and tried to save the file in `/var/www/html`. But this is the error that I'm getting:

```
Could not save the file “/var/www/html/Untitled Document 1”. You do not have the permissions necessary to save the file. Please check that you typed the location correctly and try again.
```

I tried everything I knew but all failed.
Can you help me?

Comment: **Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!** Can you provide details on how you are saving the file in the mentioned folder? Also, it will be helpful if you add the editor you are using to save the file. Please edit the answer, not to comment on the same.

Answer (score 0):

It is both a permission problem, AND a methodology problem.

In reverse order, it's better (safer, less prone to error, capable of handling multipart objects, other Comp Sci reasons, ...) to develop your software elsewhere (a subdirectory of `$HOME`) and, when ready, copy it over with `sudo cp` (or add yourself to the group, if group access is allowed (see `ls -ld  /var/www/html`). Also, pick a more meaningful filename than "`Untitled Document 1`". Read `man sudo cp php`

One must have Write access (the second bit of the appropriate permission mask, `0x02`) a directory to be able to create a file in that directory. (see `ls -ld  /var/www/html`). Lacking this access causes the error message.

Comment: thank you so much.

Comment: @gtmgtm Please click the checkmark to "accept" my answer, if it solved your problem, and might help others.